# Como mudar a janela do emulador do Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Ela não possui barra superior com os botões de fechar, minimizar e maximizar. Não consigo movê-la, fica fixa no canto esquerdo da tela e nunca carrega o app de teste "hello word". Tentei emular com o próprio smartphone mas não carregou também. Demora muito? Quanto tempo?

Processador Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz
Memória Ram 4GB
Windows 10

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow, confira o Tour do SO para aproveitar melhor os recursos oferecidos pelo mesmo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 1):

Tente os passos a seguir:

- Selecione a janela do emular com o mouse
- Aperte **ALT+SPAÇO+M**
- Você está no modo de movimentar a tela, use as setas de navegação para posicioná-la onde desejar, aperte Enter para finalizar o modo mover

Os emuladores do Android normalmente são bastante pesados, o que você pode fazer é ao criar um emulador setar ele para usar o INTEL HAXM (Virtualização). Dê uma olhada aqui: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html veja a parte: **Configuring VM Acceleration on Windows**.